# Can I allocate memory on CUDA device for objects containing arrays of float numbers?

Tags: c++, cuda

I am working on parallel solving of identical ordinary differential equations with different initial conditions. I have solved this problem with OpenMP and now I want to implement similar code on GPU. Specifically, I want to allocate memory on device for floats in class constructor and then deallocate it in destructor. It doesn't work for me since I get my executable "terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)". Is it possible to use classes, constructors and destructors in CUDA?

By the way, I am newbie in CUDA and not very experienced in C++ either.

I attach the code in case I have described my problem poorly.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

template<class ode_sys>
class solver: public ode_sys 
{
    public:
    int *nn;
    float *t,*tt,*dt,*x,*xx,*m0,*m1,*m2,*m3;

    using ode_sys::rhs_sys;

    __host__ solver(int n): ode_sys(n)
    { //here I try to allocate memory. It works malloc() and doesn't with cudaMalloc() 
        size_t size=sizeof(float)*n;
        cudaMalloc((void**)&nn,sizeof(int));
        *nn=n;
        cudaMalloc((void**)&t,sizeof(float));
        cudaMalloc((void**)&tt,sizeof(float));
        cudaMalloc((void**)&dt,sizeof(float));
        cudaMalloc((void**)&x,size);
        cudaMalloc((void**)&xx,size);
        cudaMalloc((void**)&m0,size);
        cudaMalloc((void**)&m1,size);
        cudaMalloc((void**)&m2,size);
        cudaMalloc((void**)&m3,size);
    }

    __host__ ~solver()
    {
        cudaFree(nn);
        cudaFree(t);
        cudaFree(tt);
        cudaFree(dt);
        cudaFree(x);
        cudaFree(xx);
        cudaFree(m0);
        cudaFree(m1);
        cudaFree(m2);
        cudaFree(m3);
    }

    __host__ __device__ void rk4()
    {//this part is not important now. 
    }
};

class ode 
{
    private:
    int *nn;

    public:
    float *eps,*d;

    __host__ ode(int n)
    {
        cudaMalloc((void**)&nn,sizeof(int));
        *nn=n;
        cudaMalloc((void**)&eps,sizeof(float));
        size_t size=sizeof(float)*n;
        cudaMalloc((void**)&d,size);
    }

    __host__ ~ode()
    {
        cudaFree(nn);
        cudaFree(eps);
        cudaFree(d);
    }

    __host__ __device__ float f(float x_,float y_,float z_,float d_)
    {
        return d_+*eps*(sinf(x_)+sinf(z_)-2*sinf(y_));
    }

    __host__ __device__ void rhs_sys(float *t,float *dt,float *x,float *dx)
    {
    }
};

//const float pi=3.14159265358979f;

__global__ void solver_kernel(int m,int n,solver<ode> *sys_d)
{
    int index = threadIdx.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x;

    //actually ode numerical evaluation should be here
    for (int l=index;l<m;l+=stride)
    {//this is just to check that i can run kernel
        printf("%d Hello \n", l);
    }
}

int main ()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::time_t start_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(start);
    cout << "started computation at " << std::ctime(&start_time);

    int m=128,n=4,l;// i want to run 128 threads, n is dimension of ode

    size_t size=sizeof(solver<ode>(n));
    solver<ode> *sys_d;   //an array of objects
    cudaMalloc(&sys_d,size*m);    //nvprof shows that this array is allocated

    for (l=0;l<m;l++)
    {
        new (sys_d+l) solver<ode>(n);   //it doesn't work as it meant to
    }

    solver_kernel<<<1,m>>>(m,n,sys_d);   

    for (l=0;l<m;l++)
    {
        (sys_d+l)->~solver<ode>();    //it doesn't work as it meant to
    }
    cudaFree(sys_d);    //it works

    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;
    std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
    std::cout << "finished computation at " << std::ctime(&end_time) << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";

    return 0;
}

//end of file
```

Comment: If an answer solved your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

#### Distinguish host-side and device-side memory

As other answer also state:

- GPU (global) memory you allocate with `cudaMalloc()` is *not accessible* by code running on the CPU; and
- System memory (aka host memorY) you allocate in plain C++ (with `std::vector`, with `std::make_unique`, with `new` etc.) is *not accessible* by code running on the GPU.

So, you need to allocate both host-side and device-side memory. For a simple example of working with both device-side and host-side memory see the [CUDA `vectorAdd` sample program](https://github.com/zchee/cuda-sample/blob/master/0_Simple/vectorAdd/vectorAdd.cu).

<sub>(Actually, you can also make a special kind of allocation which *is* accessible from both the device and the host; this is [Unified Memory](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/unified-memory-cuda-beginners/). But let's ignore that for now since we're dealing with the basics.)</sub>

#### Don't live in the kingdom of nouns

> Specifically, I want to allocate memory on device for floats in class constructor and then deallocate it in destructor.

I'm not sure you really want to do that. You seem to be taking a more Java-esque approach, in which everything you do is noun-centric, i.e. classes are used for everything: You don't solve equations, you have an "equation solver". You don't "do X", you have an "XDoer" class etc. Why not just have a (templated) function which solves an ODE system, returning the solution? Are you using your "solver" in any other way?

(this point is inspired by Steve Yegge's blog post, [Execution in the Kingdom of Nouns](https://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html).)

#### Try to avoid allocating and de-allocating yourself

In well-written modern C++, we try to [avoid direct, manual allocation of memory](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-mallocfree) (that's a link to the C++ Core Programming Guidelines by the way). Now, it's true that you free your memory with the destructor, so it's not all that bad, but I'd really consider using [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) on the host and something equivalent on the device (like `cuda::memory::unique_ptr` from my Modern-C++ CUDA API wrapper [`cuda-api-wrappers`](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/) library); or a GPU-oriented container class like [`thrust`](https://developer.nvidia.com/thrust)'s device vector.

#### Check for errors

You really must *check for errors* after you call CUDA API functions. And this is doubly necessary after you launch a kernel. When you call a C++ standard library code, it throws an exception on error; CUDA's runtime API is C-like, and doesn't know about exceptions. It will just fail and set some error variable you need to check.

So, either you write error checks, like in the `vectorAdd()` sample I linked to above, or you get some library to exhibit more standard-library-like behavior. `cuda-api-wrappers` and `thrust` will both do that - on different levels of abstraction; and so will other libraries/frameworks.

Comment: It seems like I am doing it all wrong. The idea was to create and access data in objects like obj[index1]->array[index2]. That prevents confusion with indices like in array[index1][index2], allows me to easily create similar objects with slightly different properties etc. It looks like very hard thing to do on gpu. I managed to allocate memory on device:
` solver<ode> *sys_d[m];
 
    for (l=0;l<m;l++)
 {
        sys_d[l] = new solver<ode>(n);
    }`
My pointers to objects are on host, data inside objects are on device, so it doesn`t work. I fail to create array of objects on device.

Answer (score 1):

You need an array on the host side and one on the device side.

Initialize the host array, then copy it to the device array with `cudaMemcpy`. The destruction has to be done on the host side again.

An alternative would be to initialize the array from the device, you would need to put `__device__` in front of your constructor, then just use `malloc`.

Comment: So I can do this without cudaMalloc?

Comment: compute capability 2.x and upwards support allocating memory from device code, so if you have that, you don't have to use `cudaMalloc`

Comment: but if you don't need to allocate memory from device side, it's normally better to do it from host side performance wise

Answer (score 0):

You can not dereference pointer to device memory in host code:

```
__host__ ode(int n)
{
    cudaMalloc((void**)&nn,sizeof(int));
    *nn=n; // !!! ERROR
    cudaMalloc((void**)&eps,sizeof(float));
    size_t size=sizeof(float)*n;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d,size);
}
```

You will have to copy the values with cudaMemcpy.
(Or use the parameters of a `__global__` function.)